# Reading json data line by line in Cherrypy

Tags: python, json, rest, curl, cherrypy

I have json data that is going to be coming to my server in the following format:

```
{"line":"one"}
{"line":"two"}
{"line":"three"}
```

While I realize that this is not valid json format I have no control on how this data is reaching me. I need to be able to read the data line by line

Now I have a very simple Cherrypy server setup to accept the POST request. Here is the function that handles the POST request:

```
class PostEvent(object):
    exposed = True
    def POST(self, **urlParams):
        cl = cherrypy.request.headers['Content-Length']
        raw_body = cherrypy.request.body.read(int(cl))
        lines = raw_body.splitlines()
        with open('log.txt', 'w') as f:
            for line in lines:
                f.write('%s\n' % line)
```

Then I simply issue the following `curl` command to test:

```
curl -i -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST --data @test_data -u username http://test-url.com
```

Where the file `test_data` contains my json data in the format specified above. I get a 200 response, however, all of the data read from the file is on one line like below:

```
{"line":"one"}{"line":"two"}{"line":"three"}
```

It seems as if when cherrypy is reading the body it is ignoring line delimiters such as `\n`. How do I get cherrypy to read the request body as it is formatted? Or more specifically how can I read the request body line by line and not all at once?

Comment: What happens when you write something like `raw_body.count('\n')` to a file?

Comment: @MartijnPieters When I add `f.write(str(raw_body.count('\n')))` I get `0`. Even when I explicitly add the `\n` to the end of the lines I still get `0`. Could cherrpy be doing some sort of pre processing before hand?

Comment: That means that `raw_body` does *not* have newlines in it, so `.splitlines()` returns `raw_body` unchanged in a list, and you are writing it out the file as one line. Are you 100% certain that `curl` is sending the data with `\n` newlines?

Comment: @MartijnPieters That was it. Apparently if you want your data sent exactly as it is formatted with `curl` you have to use the `--data-binary` flag. If you want to make an answer, I will accept it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Ah, indeed; `--data-ascii` will mess with newlines. There, answer formulated. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot imagine CherryPy mangling data like that.

Your test to write out the newline count shows that it is much more probably that `curl` is not sending the data with newlines intact, and by the time your request handler has it all newlines have been stripped (so `raw_body.splitlines()` just returns `[raw_body]` resulting in one line being written).

Make sure you POST with the `--data-binary` switch; `-d` defaults to ASCII and could very well be altering the newlines for you:

> `-d,  --data`  is the same as `--data-ascii`. To post data purely binary, you should instead use the `--data-binary` option.

Comment: Yeap, that helped a lot